# SQL script error for passed parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cmd

I am using Command Prompt to run SQL Scripts. One of the script requires a file name which is read from a settings file (file_name=ABC) by CMD and feed to the script like so

```
sqlplus @"Script_Run" %file_name%
```

Inside the script the input is read in the line:

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR','&1.ext','R');
```

Now when I run the bat file,

the substitution happening is:

```
old: "&1.ext"
new: "ABCext"
```

the script returns **"Invalid File Operation" error**.

But when I change the script line to:

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR','&1..ext','R');
```

it works. Why does the sql script here require two dots ?
improved formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref451), the period is used to concatenate the value of a substitution variable with other characters:

> If you wish to append characters immediately after a substitution variable, use a period to separate the variable from the character. For example:

```
SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='&X.5';
Enter value for X:  20
```

> is interpreted as

```
SELECT SALARY FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID='205';
```